# Where in the Windows networking stack do WinPcap/Npcap hook/filter to "listen" for packets?

Tags: windows, networking, wireshark, winpcap

I'm investigating an issue with a process that performs IPC via a socket.  The socket is served on the local machine's NIC's IP, and the connection is made to the local machine's NIC's IP from another process on the local machine.

I expected that this would drop down the Windows networking stack at least far enough that Wireshark could see the packets.  However, it appears that this is not the case.  Therefore, I can conclude that socket IPC takes place higher in the stack [would be interesting to see if any windows event tracing (ETW) facilities would see the traffic as an IP frame].  This isn't important to this question (since this isn't stackoverflow).

Where does WinPcap/Npcap "live" in the networking stack to listen for and pass packets to wireshark?

I'm focused on modern Windows OS versions (client: 7+, 10+; server: 2008+, 2012+, 2016+).  Specifically, this client is Windows 10.

I effectively want to know where in the network stack the decision is made to "loop back" the packets to the host instead of sending them down the stack.

Thanks

Comment: Don't really, but you may have to go to the source.  https://www.winpcap.org/devel.htm the answer looks pretty complex.  See https://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_412/html/main.html, https://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_412/html/group__NPF.html

Comment: I was looking at some diagrams about the networking stack earlier to try to explain this away, while explaining IPC via sockets.  See "Client and Server Side Sockets" (http://www.codemachine.com/article_tdi.html), the filtering engine (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/network/windows-filtering-platform-architecture-overview), and the network module registrar (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/84f3858b-5dc7-4eb0-b91d-2e8bd303c28d/where-does-netiosys-sit-in-the-windows-network-stack).  But I can't say where/how exactly it's done.  An NDIS driver?

Comment: Wait, the link you posted (https://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_412/html/group__NPF.html), explains essentially what I'm asking, but not exactly. I guess... but sort of.  It might turn me directly in the direction of the answer, so thank you.

Comment: [This might be relevant](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback) but confusing, it keeps contradicting itself.

Comment: This also seems interesting, but talks about the ETW's facilities: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ndf/network-tracing-in-windows-7-architecture

Comment: You should add which specific version of Windows you're talking about, as the answer will vary greatly depending on whether you're talking about Server 2003 (XP,) or Server 2008 (Vista) or better.

Comment: Thanks Ryan.  The post has been updated.  I thought all versions with the "old" architecture are EOS?  It appears that a useful diagram (http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC34200.gif) has disappeared from the MSFT site.  Can you assist with sharing this?  Thanks!

Comment: XP and 2003 are definitely completely out of vendor support. However, that does not stop people from asking about those OSes on Serverfault. That's why I wanted to make sure. :)

Comment: I agree.  Thanks.  If anyone can explain this, I think it would be you! :D  Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is at the IP layer, unless Fast Loopback is enabled, then it is at the TCP layer.  Applications such as Network Monitor or Wireshark don't work due to the Microsoft network stack is not instrumented for capturing loopback traffic.

"The default behavior of the TCP loopback interface is to move local TCP traffic through most of the network stack, including AFD (which is essentially the kernel mode representation of a user mode TCP socket), as well as the layers corresponding to TCP and IP protocol layers."

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wincat/2012/12/05/fast-tcp-loopback-performance-and-low-latency-with-windows-server-2012-tcp-loopback-fast-path/

As an alternative, you may be able to capture on the Windows Filtering Platform (WFP) layer using Microsoft Message Analyzer:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winsdk/2014/08/15/rejoice-we-can-now-capture-loopback-traffic/